# How with div underneath?

Tags: css

I currently have have an image floating to the left, with a `<ul/>` and a `<div/>` to the right side of the image.

Comment: Can you provide an image of how you want things to look?

Comment: @torazaburo If you look at the answer below, LGSon is very close to having what I'm looking for, but it just seems that they are not being vertically centered inside the footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use display:table; and vertical-align: middle; like this:

```
<footer id="footer">
   <div class="first-column">
       <img
       id="footer-logo"
       src="testImage.png"
       />
   </div>

   <div class="second-column">
      <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
         <li style={{display: 'inline'}}>Text 1</li>
         <li style={{display: 'inline'}}>Text 2</li>
         <li style={{display: 'inline'}}>Text 3</li>
      </ul>
      <div style={{color: 'white'}}>Place me below ul</div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

And your css:

```
#footer{
   display:table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: black;
   z-index: 100;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 10px;
}

.first-column{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 50px;
}
.first-column img{
   width: 100px;
}
.second-column{
   display: table-cell;
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.second-column ul li{
   list-style: none;
   color: #ffffff;
}
.second-column div{
   color: #ffffff;
   padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Have you given it a try? It just messed up everything. The image is extremely huge and ul/div are just placed below it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close, but there are a few things throwing it off.

- The curly braces in your inline style are incorrect syntax.  Replace the curly brackets you have with quotes.
- You don't need quotes around the css value the way you have.
- Change the footer to overflow hidden (see below).
- Change the footer height to 70px so it's tall enough to show the text div.
- Make the color on the text div white so the text shows.
- Also wrap a div with overflow:hidden on it around the ul and the text div so the text div doesn't float left below the image.

  Overflow:hidden is a great trick when dealing with floats - often floated elements pop out of their parent elements and putting overflow:hidden on the parent is one way of fixing this.  The only thing this doesn't address is the vertical centering - I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that because they are vertically centered within the footer.

*edited - realized my original answer did not meet all the items you mention

http://jsbin.com/xorikisilo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: By vertically centering, I meant place all the elements in the vertically middle of the footer. If you take a look at the jsbin provided, the cat image is in the upper left corner rather than in the middle, and the `<div>` is placed slightly off from the `<ul>` when I'd like for them to be vertically centered and be aligned on starting from the left side.

Comment: Makes sense. To do this, you can:

Comment: Sorry that comment posted prematurely.  You can add padding:15px 0 on the footer (15px top and bottom padding, 0 left and right) and add a margin:0 and padding:0 style on the ul.   http://jsbin.com/qokoxitedo/1/edit?html,css,output